# Resize the images in an SSRS report instead of using fit to size or fit proportional options

Tags: reporting-services

I have images in a database that I want to display in an SSRS report. For this I have used a matrix and in this I have inserted an Image item.

Because the source image sizes are different, the images on the SSRS report are not in same size and format. I have tried the "fit to size" and "fit proportional" options to resize the images but nothing is working.

Could anyone suggest what I can do to display the images the same size in the report?

Answer (score 0):

I would use a picture editor like Paint to get the images to about the same size.

Set the picture's cell size using the larger pictur and set the **Sizing** to **CLIP** so that it always show the full image without auto-sizing them. Then change the picture to use your image field.

Answer (score 0):

I'd make a subreport that accepts parameters used to load your image such as a filename or for the case of images held in a database structure, the primary key.

Now resize the subreport to the size that you want and the image will be resized.

The issue I have with this method is that the images aren't resized properly, so the report runs out of memory after about 8 pages of high resolution images